# Remove default hyperlink from Title in SharePoint 2013 Calendar List

Tags: sandbox-solution, sharepoint-calendar

I want to remove default hyperlink from Title in SharePoint 2013 Calendar List and want to set custom link in Title. How can I perform this programatically in sandbox solution?

Thanks.

Comment: You can explore JSLink for this.

Comment: @Asad : Thanks. Can you explain in detail how can I perform this ?

Comment: Refer https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a and http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/01/using-jslink-to-change-ui-of-sharepoint_20.html

Comment: check this one https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/2e065a9a-220b-4edd-9240-1699eea7251a/how-to-remove-hyperlink-from-sharepoint-calendar-web-part-event